# Any risk of hosting a public website on my home network? Year 2015

Tags: networking, security, asp.net, web-hosting, windows-8.1

I have read the following post but it was already 6 years ago so I'm wondering if anything has changed over the last few years in terms of security because I heard windows firewall has been improved alot:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624815/risks-of-hosting-public-web-site-right-on-my-network

I have created my first website using ASP.NET and SQL Server and successfully hosted on IIS (on port 80). In order to make it so that the website is visible to everyone in the world, I logged-in to my router and portforwarded port 80 to my home pc ip address and set the windows 8 firewall inbound setting to open up port 80. Now, whenever I visit my public ip address, my website loads successfully. Everytime I block port 80 from my windows firewall, visits to my website is blocked as intended. Since only port 80 is opened and the port is setup specifically for my website hosted on IIS, would there be any security risks of getting hacked? I'm using the computer as my personal computer as well. And there are 3 more computers that are connected to my router wirelessly. Would hosting a website on my home computer make the other computers and my home computer be more vulnerable to hacks? Would buying a new computer exclusively for hosting website help reduce the risks?

I have considered doing the following methods setting up DMZ and Intranet routers: http://dfarq.homeip.net/2011/11/how-to-make-a-dmz-with-two-routers/ http://www.pcwintech.com/how-setup-two-or-more-routers-together-port-forwarding-port-triggering

but I cannot make it work. Even if this method works, would it be necessary for today's standard?

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend it. What happens if your house loses power? What happens if the router DID get hacked? What happens if Windows DID get hacked? What happens if your IP address changes (you don't have a static, do you)?

Comment: Nope, still not s viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

As David already wrote in his comment.
It is not recommended to host your Website at home.

There's a lot of problems you need to solve:

- Public IP Address
- Bandwidth at home (normally slow upload speed)
- Security issues
- Updating Servers, Pachting devices and so on

In the year 2015 you got cheep professional hostings in the wild.
These providers are responsible for uplink, security questions, patching servers etc. For little money you get all what you need with no work!

I hope, I could answer your question.